# Assign Variable After Callback is Finished

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asynchronous

I am setting

```
var x = (collection.fetch({context:collection}).done(function() {
            return this.length;
        }))();
```

but since it is an asynchronous action, I need to wait to assign the variable until after the call back is finished. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you not do whatever is needed with the result directly in your `.done()` callback?

Comment: @nnnnnn I need it out of the `.done()` callback?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more context. The most likely solution will be to move everything that cares about `x` into the `done` callback. Or listen to events on `collection` and react to them.

Comment: @muistooshort I have to add a row using another function, so I need this variable for both of them.

Comment: So call this other function from the `done` callback. Or bind this other function to the collection's events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the variable in the `done()` function itself.

```
done(function() {
  //this runs when the asynchronous action is finished.
  var x = 'my value'; 
}))();
```

There's no way to know what you mean by your comment, but it sounds like you just want to do this:

```
done(function() {
  //this runs when the asynchronous action is finished.
  var x = this.length;
}))();
```

but I have no idea what `this.length;` refers to...so I can't say. There's probably some data made available to the `done()` function also...maybe you want that:

```
done(function(response) {
  //this runs when the asynchronous action is finished.
  var x = response;
}))();
```

From there, you probably want to chain a function to the promise - that's technical so I'm going to just give the simple answer and say that you could then use a callback to pass `x` where you need it:

```
done(function() {
  //this runs when the asynchronous action is finished.
  var x = this.length;
  someFunction(x);
}))();
```